# R: optimal way of computing the "product" of two vectors

Tags: r

Let's assume that I have a vector

```
r <- rnorm(4)
```

and a matrix `W` of dimension 20000*200 for example:

```
W <- matrix(rnorm(20000*200),20000,200)
```

I want to compute a new matrix `M` of dimension 5000*200 such that `m11 <- r%*%W[1:4,1]`, `m21 <- r%*%W[5:8,1]`, `m12 <- r%*%W[1:4,2]` etc. (i.e. grouping rows 4-by-4 and computing the product).

What's the optimal (speed,memory) way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to run fastest for me:

```
array(r %*% array(W, c(4, 20000 * 200 / 4)), c(5000, 200))
```

Comment: And uses less memory as I checked

Answer (score 3):

First on my mind is `apply` over shorter dim:

```
M <- apply(W, 2, function(x) r%*%matrix(x,4,5000))

m11 <- r%*%W[1:4,1]
m21 <- r%*%W[5:8,1]
m12 <- r%*%W[1:4,2]

m11 - M[1,1]
#      [,1]
# [1,]    0
m21 - M[2,1]
#      [,1]
# [1,]    0
m12 - M[1,2]

#      [,1]
# [1,]    0
```

Profiled [kohske answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037516/r-optimal-way-of-computing-the-product-of-two-vectors/3037804#3037804):

```
M <- apply(array(W,c(4,5000,200)), 3, function(x) r%*%x)
```

to iterated over shorter dim (again).

Comment: you solution is much faster than my solution. great!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is optimal in speed or memory, but probably one of the simple way:

```
m<-apply(array(W,c(4,5000,200)),c(2,3),"%*%",r)


> m[1,1:10]==r%*%W[1:4,1:10]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE  TRUE
> m[2,1:10]==r%*%W[5:8,1:10]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE  TRUE
```